# Truncate number of digit of double value in C#

Tags: c#

How can i truncate the leading digit of double value in C#,I have tried Math.Round(doublevalue,2) but not giving the require result. and i didn't find any other method in Math class.

For example i have value 12.123456789 and i only need 12.12.

Comment: What should be the result when you give 12.12890?

Comment: What **phoenix** is asking is do you want to round it to 12.13, or just truncate it to 12.12... ?

Comment: i want just truncate all digit after 2.

Comment: Then Math.Round won't be an option

Answer (score 35, accepted):

EDIT: It's been pointed out that these approaches *round* the value instead of *truncating*. It's hard to genuinely truncate a `double` value because it's not really in the right base... but truncating a `decimal` value is more feasible.

You should use an appropriate format string, either [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) or [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx), e.g.

```
string x = d.ToString("0.00");
```

or

```
string x = d.ToString("F2");
```

It's worth being aware that a double value itself doesn't "know" how many decimal places it has. It's only when you convert it to a string that it really makes sense to do so. Using `Math.Round` will get the closest double value to `x.xx00000` (if you see what I mean) but it almost certainly won't be the exact value `x.xx00000` due to the way binary floating point types work.

If you need this for anything *other* than string formatting, you should consider using `decimal` instead. What does the value actually represent?

I have articles on [binary floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/floatingpoint.aspx) and [decimal floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/decimal.aspx) in .NET which you may find useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i dont want to convert value in string, then back to double again, i have to store value like.
var newVal=Math.Round(oldValue,2) or some other function.

Comment: @Firoz: to string and back to double will not help you anyway: if double can't represent "12.34" exactly, then you *will* get extra decimals. It is simple not possible to store a double with only two decimals.

Comment: Wow, by sheer chance this is the second accepted answer by Jon Skeet in the last hour on here that has completely failed me.  This rounds, and the OP asked to truncate!  So 3.55555555 becomes 3.56.  And I even up-voted this stupid answer and now I can't take it back!  This site is starting to suck - people get up-voted just because of their existing reputation (like "oh it's Jon Skeet so it must be right!").

Comment: Yep, according to the MSDN documentation on [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and [Custom Numeric Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx), both of the approaches Jon outlined in his answer round, not truncate. :(

Comment: @Jon: Don't worry, according to the upvote count, you're not the only one who didn't do their homework. ;)

Comment: Jon Skeet's articles are now located here: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/floatingpoint.aspx and here: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/decimal.aspx. The original links posted by him somehow get classified as "web based email" in my org's web filters :)

Comment: @mishrsud: I've updated the links - `pobox.com` is a general redirection service, for both web and email - it *does* have a web-based email viewer aspect, which is probably what's confusing the filter.

Answer (score 26):

What have you tried? It works as expected for me:

```
double original = 12.123456789;

double truncated = Math.Truncate(original * 100) / 100;

Console.WriteLine(truncated);    // displays 12.12
```

Answer (score 4):

```
double original = 12.123456789;  

double truncated = Truncate(original, 2);  

Console.WriteLine(truncated.ToString());
// or 
// Console.WriteLine(truncated.ToString("0.00"));
// or 
// Console.WriteLine(Truncate(original, 2).ToString("0.00"));


public static double Truncate(double value, int precision)
{
    return Math.Truncate(value * Math.Pow(10, precision)) / Math.Pow(10, precision);
}
```

Comment: Your solution won't work for 5.02. If you call Truncate(5.02) you'l receive 5.01 because 5.02*100=501.99999999999994

Answer (score 3):

This code....

```
double x = 12.123456789;
Console.WriteLine(x);
x = Math.Round(x, 2);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Returns this....

```
12.123456789
12.12
```

What is your desired result that is different?

If you want to keep the value as a double, and just strip of any digits after the second decimal place and not actually round the number then you can simply subtract 0.005 from your number so that round will then work. For example.

```
double x = 98.7654321;
Console.WriteLine(x);
double y = Math.Round(x - 0.005, 2);
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

Produces this...

```
98.7654321
98.76
```

Comment: if x = 12.125 then he will get 12.13 which seems to not be what he is wanting.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
double num = 12.12890;
double truncatedNum = ((int)(num * 100))/100.00;
```

Comment: I did some benchmarking and this method is 2x faster than original Math.Truncate. Thanks for sharing

Comment: To gain a bit more performance replace /100 with *0.01 But it is already micro optimisation. I do favorize this answer.

Answer (score 3):

This could work (although not tested):

```
public double RoundDown(this double value, int digits)
{
     int factor = Math.Pow(10,digits);

     return Math.Truncate(value * factor) / factor;
}
```

Then you simply use it like this:

```
double rounded = number.RoundDown(2);
```

Comment: digits and factor should be double as well. Besides that, works like a charm :)

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of answers using Math.Truncate(double).
However, the approach using Math.Truncate(double) can lead to incorrect results. 
For instance, it will return 5.01 truncating 5.02, because multiplying of double values doesn't work precisely and 5.02*100=501.99999999999994

[image: 5.02*100=501.99999999999994]

If you really need this precision, consider, converting to Decimal before truncating.

```
public static double Truncate(double value, int precision)
{
    decimal power = (decimal)Math.Pow(10, precision);
    return (double)(Math.Truncate((decimal)value * power) / power);
}
```

Still, this approach is ~10 times slower.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's something more .netty out there but why not just:-

```
double truncVal = Math.Truncate(val * 100) / 100;
double remainder = val-truncVal;
```

Comment: The "decimal" type might offer less risk of a floating point rounding error.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET Core 3.0 and later versions, three additional rounding strategies are available through the [`MidpointRounding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-5.0) enumeration. In this case  `MidpointRounding.ToZero` or `MidpointRounding.ToNegativeInfinity` Can be of interest.

The following:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(12.128, 2,MidpointRounding.ToZero));
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(12.123456789, 2,MidpointRounding.ToZero));
```

Results in:

```
12.12
12.12
```

[Demo @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQ65IJwAoCyAhsABYB0ASgPbQAmuSCZjAHADQAECb+AlrQAcqvKMGp0RAczIAVKgC0ApmCoBKVQG5MOAsXLio9RswQBmACwBWAGwB2Ftk7c+g4aIO0pshcrWagA=)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to have two points after the decimal without rounding the number, the following should work

```
string doubleString = doublevalue.ToString("0.0000"); //To ensure we have a sufficiently lengthed string to avoid index issues
Console.Writeline(doubleString
             .Substring(0, (doubleString.IndexOf(".") +1) +2));
```

The second parameter of substring is the count, and IndexOf returns to zero-based index, so we have to add one to that before we add the 2 decimal values.

This answer is assuming that the value should NOT be rounded

Answer (score 0):

For vb.net use this extension:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module DoubleExtensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function Truncate(dValue As Double, digits As Integer)

        Dim factor As Integer
        factor = Math.Pow(10, digits)

        Return Math.Truncate(dValue * factor) / factor

    End Function
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a little formatting class that I put together which can add gaps and all sorts.

Here is one of the methods that takes in a decimal and return different amounts of decimal places based on the decimal display setting in the app

```
 public decimal DisplayDecimalFormatting(decimal input, bool valueIsWeightElseMoney)
    {
        string inputString = input.ToString();

        if (valueIsWeightElseMoney)
        {
            int appDisplayDecimalCount = Program.SettingsGlobal.DisplayDecimalPlacesCount;

            if (appDisplayDecimalCount == 3)//0.000
            {
                inputString = String.Format("{0:#,##0.##0}", input, displayCulture);
            }
            else if (appDisplayDecimalCount == 2)//0.00
            {
                inputString = String.Format("{0:#,##0.#0}", input, displayCulture);
            }
            else if (appDisplayDecimalCount == 1)//0.0
            {
                inputString = String.Format("{0:#,##0.0}", input, displayCulture);
            }
            else//appDisplayDecimalCount 0   //0
            {
                inputString = String.Format("{0:#,##0}", input, displayCulture);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            inputString = String.Format("{0:#,##0.#0}", input, displayCulture);
        }

        //Check if worked and return if worked, else return 0
        bool itWorked = false;
        decimal returnDec = 0.00m;
        itWorked = decimal.TryParse(inputString, out returnDec);

        if (itWorked)
        {
            return returnDec;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0.00m;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```cs
object number = 12.123345534;   
string.Format({"0:00"},number.ToString());
```