# Decimal number formatting

Tags: c#

I want to display the decimal numbers with one digit after the point. I don't want to round of the digits.

Example:

My data type is decimal.

If the Number is 123.489 or 123.411  then I want to display as 123.4

I tried `number.ToString("###.#");` It is round of my numbers.

also tried this

```
(decimal)(Math.Truncate((double)(TradingMarginLiveValue * 10)) / 10);
```

It is working Fine for me.

But, is there any simple way to do this ?

Comment: Multiply by ten, floor it, divide by ten.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Math.Round(number, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Comment: except they seem to want TowardZero which doesn't exist. Or maybe I don't like the name... ;)

Answer (score 0):

As `Math.Round(decimal d)` does
"Rounds a decimal value to the nearest **integral** value."
You can't use Round in any way even with digit choice, because it will rond to an Int considering the selected digits.
Your method seem to be the pretty Best as suggests [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426857/truncate-number-of-digit-of-double-value-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You are suggested to use number.ToString("F1"). It is also rounds the value

Comment: The best rated answer suggests it yes, but not the ther ones that mainly suggest to use your method

Answer (score 0):

```
(int)(TradingMarginLiveValue * 10)/10M
```