# C# - Restrict double variable to two decimal places

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, floating-point, double

I am using Unity Engine to make a game.
I am using a double variable and want it to only display the number till two decimal places.

```
public double nos = 0;
```

For eg: if nos = 17.2369...;
I want it to display nos = 17.23;

P.S.: I don't want to round it off or smt.

How to make that happen?

Comment: If you want exactly 2 places, you _will_ need to round to some extent. As is, this question has no solution since you exclude the only thing that would make one possible.

Comment: This answer looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54184194/1974021 provided it is for display purposes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a float number without rounding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946168/how-to-format-a-float-number-without-rounding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, string formatting also does some rounding.
This should work then:

```
double num = 15.345324;
num = Math.Truncate(100 * num) / 100;
// num = 15.34
```

Use 10 to the power of decimal places (here: 100) you want to have as factor.

100 -> 2dps

1000 -> 3dps

etc.

Edit: In a more general way one could do sth like this

```
double num = 12.3456789;
double numOfDecimals = 2;
num = Math.Truncate(Math.Pow(10, numOfDecimals) * num) / Math.Pow(10, numOfDecimals);
```

Comment: okay thanks. Where would I write 2dps and 3dps stuff.

Comment: See my updated answer for a more generalized approach:)